# Always getting null values in controller for ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried an ajax post from my view as shown below (using jQuery).

Complete Solution [Here.](http://ubuntuone.com/3MjtnTGN9z1KfwWysYyRCL)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var kk = {
                    Address1: "423 Judy Road",
                    Address2: "1001",
                    City: "New York",
                    State: "NY",
                    ZipCode: "10301",
                    Country: "USA"
                };
                console.log(JSON.stringify(kk));
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Check',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(kk),
                    dataType:"json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.success);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And received it in a controller (the method always invoked)

```
public ActionResult Check(AddressInfo addressInfo)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
```

Model [here](http://pastie.org/8383546),
But when I tried to access (break point checked) the properties of the object (`AddressInfo`) it always showed `null` value. I tried without stringifying and stringifying. I 'm learning MVC now and a beginner. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you're using ASP.NET MVC 2 and support for model binding from JSON wasn't added until ASP.NET MVC 3.

You can add that functionality to ASP.NET MVC 2 though. Phil Haack has a post describing that, with a link to sample code at the end: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: Can I use JSON.stringify(person) instead of $.toJSON(person).

Comment: Yes, they do the same thing in browsers that support JSON.stringify. In old browsers (pre-IE8, essentially), you need to include json2.js in order to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
return this.Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If this don't work just change the request parameter from `AddressInfo` to String at the controller side.
This will definitely work!!

Comment: Thanks buddy !!. I am glad that I can be helpful

Comment: srsly mind blowing answer i was searching it for last many days and u gave the soultion thanks alottttttt

Comment: its always null returned. I'm working on MVC2 and dont know whats happening. Its always null

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType` as `json` in `Ajax` and pass `addressInfo` in `data parameter` like,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Check',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype:'json',
    data: {addressInfo:kk},
    success:function(data){
    ....
    ....
 });
```

Comment: But still getting null

Comment: Do i want to stringify the data?

Comment: No, there is no need of it, but check in `console` that your `ajax url` is hitting the `server` or not?

Comment: Always the method will be invoked without any error. The returned JSON  is getting perfectly on success function.

Comment: ajax url always hit the url properly and the controller method will also get invoked. But the object won't contain any value (just `null` values)

Comment: `Stringify` the `json` and try

Comment: Added the link to complete solution. Please find it and give an answer

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370062/posting-json-data-via-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-4-controller-action

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass data in querystring way like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = "Address1=423 Judy Road&Address2=1001&City=New York&State=NY&ZipCode=10301&Country=USA";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Check',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.success);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I want to pass only JSON data. That's how most of the ajax posts work.

Comment: Ok, so don't pass a JSON string but a JSON object.

Comment: still its null value getting in the controller