# HTML as parameter JSON MVC

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc-2, parameters

I need to pass **html** as parameter using `json asp.net mvc2`

I am trying to do like this:

```
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: "/DefaultView/GeneratePDF",
            data: { "pdf": JSON.parse($("#displayContainer").html()) },
            success: function (data) {
                //nothing here
            }
        });
```

but it throws the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " error.

using stringify() I am getting null here:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)] 
    public virtual ActionResult GeneratePDF(string pdf)
    {
        pdf <---
```

Does anyone have any idea what should I to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **stringify** method of JSON:

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         url: "/DefaultView/GeneratePDF",
         data: { "pdf": JSON.stringify($("#displayContainer").html()) }, //change to stringify
         success: function (data) {
         //nothing here
        }
      });
```

**EDIT**: If you are using **MVC 2 Model Binding to JSON is not supported**. See this post - [Always getting null values in controller for ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221594/always-getting-null-values-in-controller-for-ajax-post)

Comment: Are you actually getting inside that method though?

Comment: yes... bud pdf is null and if I call `console.log(JSON.stringify($("#displayContainer").html()))` it returns elements.

Comment: What do you get when you run JSON.stringify($("#displayContainer").html() in the console for the developer tools? Do you see that return a result?

Comment: Yes... it returns as expected.

Comment: Try adding  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: actually just remove the content type completely

Comment: wait are you using MVC 2?

Comment: yes, I am. please.. tell me that there are a solution.

Comment: Not looking good for you. You can't use stringify with MVC 2 because the model binder will not know how to parse it correctly. And without stringify I am not sure how to send HTML to the server from $.ajax...

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it though

Comment: you are right... I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221594/always-getting-null-values-in-controller-for-ajax-post?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the help of this link:

[link](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

... I needed to reference `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` and to add a call in my application_start (global.asax) like this:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

I also needed to make use of [json2js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

As @Jason Roell said, We can't use **stringify** with MVC 2.. the **model binder** doesn't knows how to parse the value correctly.

After all, everything works as expected.

Thanks.

I hope it helps someone.